# Gnuplot table of values and delta values (quotient)

Tags: gnuplot

Is there a way to plot a table of values and delta values (quotient) similar to the image below using gnuplot?

[image: Sample Graph]

Comment: You can use the `labels` plotting style to place data values from a data file somewhere. Or you could use the `xticlabel` function to create new labels on the x-axis with values from a data file. But you cannot create real tables (only with a lot of extra work)

Comment: thanks for your comment. If you post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `labels` plotting style to place data values from a data file somewhere in your plot. Or you could use the `xticlabel` function to create new labels on the x-axis with values from a data file. But you cannot create real tables (only with a lot of extra work).